# In React JS is there a reason why the useState() hook doesn't merge object props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm a bit curious why did they implement it that way and we have to destructure and override the previous object instead of it being done so automatically by the hook. Was it on purpose for some specific reason?

```
setObject(...object, objProp : newProp) //why??
```

**EDIT**: I'm thinking now that maybe they left it that way to allow for greater flexibility in case we want to replace the entire object with the new props instead of simply updating the old ones.. I could be wrong though

Comment: Another reason is that because you can have multiple useState hooks in one component you can split your state up into logically separate pieces. Try having multiple useState hooks with simple data instead of one useState hook with a complex object and see how it goes.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've been doing, but it does get a bit annoying having to use the spread operator when it makes more sense to group multiple state variables into an object or when I have to type the multitude of [state, setState]=useState() for each variable instead of dumping them all into an object

Comment: If it's really bothering you then it shouldn't be too hard to make a `useMergeState` custom hook that behaves like you want

Comment: Good idea! I'll have to look into making custom hooks.. haven't yet done that before. This is literally my only pet peeve with functional components. Thanks for the suggestion!